# How does the light state works in an effect file of DirectX

Tags: directx

I am learning DirectX effect and I know that all the fixed pipline render state can be set in an .fx file, when I want to set a point light in an .fx file, how to compute the final pixel color? what is the light[0] come from? below is the code of the .fx file, I don't know how to write the pixel shader part(BasicPS) to compute the final color.

```
    // World, View and Projection Matrix 
    uniform extern float4x4 gWVP;  

    // Output Vertex structure 
    struct OutputVS 
    { 
          float4 posH : POSITION0; 
    }; 

    OutputVS BasicVS(float4 posL : POSITION0) 
    { 

          // Zero out our output. 
          OutputVS outVS = (OutputVS)0; 

          // Transform to homogeneous clip space. 
          outVS.posH = mul(posL, gWVP); 

          // Done--return the output. 
          return outVS; 
    } 

    float4 BasicPS() : COLOR 
    { 
        //What to write here? 
    } 

    technique Tech1 
    { 
        pass p0 
        { 
            vertexShader = compile vs_2_0 BasicVS(); 
            pixelShader  = compile ps_2_0 BasicPS(); 

            Lighting = True; 
            LightEnable[0] = True; 
            LightType[0] = POINT; 

            // Light color is white 
            LightAmbient[0] = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.0f}; 
            LightDiffuse[0] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}; 
            LightSpecular[0] = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.0f}; 

            // Light position 
            LightPosition[0] = {10.0f, 10.0f, -5.0f}; 

            // Light range 
            LightRange[0] = 1000.0f; 

            // Light falloff 
            LightFalloff[0] = 1.0f; 

            // Attenuations 
            LightAttenuation0[0] = 1.0f; 
            LightAttenuation1[0] = 0.0f; 
            LightAttenuation2[0] = 0.0f; 
        } 
    } 


the cpp file of this program as below

    #include <d3dx9.h>
    #include <MMSystem.h>

    LPDIRECT3D9             g_pD3D              = NULL ; // Used to create the D3DDevice
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9       g_pd3dDevice        = NULL ; // Our rendering device
    ID3DXMesh*              g_pTeapotMesh       = NULL ; // Hold the teapot
    ID3DXEffect*            g_pEffect           = NULL ; // Effect interface
    bool                    g_bActive           = true ; // Is window active?

    // Handles for effects
    D3DXHANDLE g_hWVP;      // world, view and projection matrix handle.
    D3DXHANDLE g_hTech;     // Technique handle

    #define SAFE_RELEASE(P) if(P){ P->Release(); P = NULL;}

    HRESULT BuildEffect()
    {
        char* effectFile = "./PointLight.fx";

        ID3DXBuffer* errors = 0;

        // Create Effect from file
        HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(
            g_pd3dDevice,
            effectFile, 
            NULL,
            NULL,
            D3DXSHADER_DEBUG,
            NULL,
            &g_pEffect,
            &errors);
        if( errors )
            MessageBox(0, (char*)errors->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);

        g_hWVP  = g_pEffect->GetParameterByName(0, "gWVP");
        g_hTech = g_pEffect->GetTechniqueByName("Tech1");

        return D3D_OK;
    }

    HRESULT SetupPointLight()
    {
        D3DLIGHT9 pointLight;
        ZeroMemory(&pointLight, sizeof(pointLight));

        // Set light
        g_pd3dDevice->SetLight(0, &pointLight);

        return D3D_OK;
    }

    HRESULT SetupMaterial()
    {
    D3DMATERIAL9 material;
    ZeroMemory(&material, sizeof(material));

    D3DXCOLOR red = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0);
    material.Ambient = red;
    material.Diffuse = red;
    material.Specular = red;
    material.Emissive = D3DXCOLOR(0, 0, 0, 0);
    material.Power = 2.0f; // only affect specular color

    g_pd3dDevice->SetMaterial(&material);

    return D3D_OK;
    }

    HRESULT InitD3D( HWND hWnd )
    {
        // Create the D3D object, which is needed to create the D3DDevice.
        if( NULL == ( g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION ) ) )
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Create D3D9 object failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return E_FAIL;
        }

        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 
        ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );

        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE; // use window mode, not full screen
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

        // Create device
        if( FAILED( g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
            D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
            &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice ) ) )
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Create D3D9 device failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return E_FAIL;
        }

        // Create teapot
        D3DXCreateTeapot(g_pd3dDevice, &g_pTeapotMesh, NULL) ;

        // Build effect
        BuildEffect();

        return S_OK;
    }

    void DrawTeapot()
    {
        // translate model to origin
        D3DXMATRIX world ;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&world, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ;
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &world) ;

        // set view
        D3DXVECTOR3 eyePt(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f) ;
        D3DXVECTOR3 upVec(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) ;
        D3DXVECTOR3 lookCenter(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ;

        D3DXMATRIX view ;
        D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&view, &eyePt, &lookCenter, &upVec) ;
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &view) ;

        // set projection
        D3DXMATRIX proj ;
        D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&proj, D3DX_PI / 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1000.0f) ;
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &proj) ;

        D3DXMATRIX worldviewproj = world * view * proj;

        // Set matrix
        g_pEffect->SetMatrix(g_hWVP, &worldviewproj);

        // Set technique
        g_pEffect->SetTechnique(g_hTech);

        // Render pass
        UINT numPass = 0;
        g_pEffect->Begin(&numPass, 0);
        g_pEffect->BeginPass(0);
        g_pTeapotMesh->DrawSubset(0);
        g_pEffect->EndPass();
        g_pEffect->End();
    }

    VOID Cleanup()
    {
        SAFE_RELEASE(g_pTeapotMesh) ;
        SAFE_RELEASE(g_pd3dDevice) ;
        SAFE_RELEASE(g_pD3D) ;
    }

    void Render(float timeDelta)
    {
        if (!g_bActive)
        {
            Sleep(50) ;
        }

        SetupMaterial();

        SetupPointLight();

        // Clear the back-buffer to a RED color
        g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0), 1.0f, 0 );

        // Begin the scene
        if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
        {
            // Draw teapot 
            DrawTeapot();

            // End the scene
            g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
        }

        // Present the back-buffer contents to the display
        g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    }

    LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {
        switch( msg )
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            {
                switch( wParam )
                {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    SendMessage( hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0 );
                    break ;
                default:
                    break ;
                }
            }
            return 0 ;

        case WM_SIZE:
            if(wParam == SIZE_MAXHIDE || wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
                g_bActive = false;
            else
                g_bActive = true;
            return 0;

        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
            if(wParam == TRUE)
                g_bActive = true ;
            else
                g_bActive = false ;
            return 0 ;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            Cleanup();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;
        }

        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
    }

    INT WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
    {
        WNDCLASSEX winClass ;

        winClass.lpszClassName = "Teapot";
        winClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        winClass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        winClass.lpfnWndProc   = MsgProc;
        winClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
        winClass.hIcon         = NULL ;
        winClass.hIconSm       = NULL ;
        winClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
        winClass.hbrBackground = NULL ;
        winClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
        winClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        winClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;

        RegisterClassEx (&winClass) ;  

        HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,  
            winClass.lpszClassName,     // window class name
            "Teapot",                   // window caption
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
            32,                         // initial x position
            32,                         // initial y position
            600,                        // initial window width
            600,                        // initial window height
            NULL,                       // parent window handle
            NULL,                       // window menu handle
            hInstance,                  // program instance handle
            NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

        // Create window failed
        if(hWnd == NULL)
        {
            MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Create Window failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return -1 ;
        }

        // Initialize Direct3D
        if( SUCCEEDED(InitD3D(hWnd)))
        { 
            // Show the window
            ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
            UpdateWindow( hWnd );

            MSG msg ; 
            ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );
            PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_NOREMOVE );

            // Get last time
            static DWORD lastTime = timeGetTime();

            while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)  
            {
                if(PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) != 0)
                {
                    TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
                    DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
                }
                else // Render the game if there is no message to process
                {
                    // Get current time
                    DWORD currTime  = timeGetTime();

                    // Calculate time elapsed
                    float timeDelta = (currTime - lastTime) * 0.001f;

                    // Render
                    Render(timeDelta) ;

                    // Update last time to current time for next loop
                    lastTime = currTime;
                }
            }
        }

        UnregisterClass(winClass.lpszClassName, hInstance) ;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to use the Fixed Function Pipeline, leave the PixelShader away. It is valid to only define a VertexShader. Set the PixelShader to NULL.

Comment: I try to set the pixelShader = null; and setup a light in my .cpp code, but there is no color appeared on my model, so I guess, whether the light state works?

Comment: Do you have a material with the proper attributes? Btw, POINT lights don't have a `Falloff` value.

Comment: yes, I have set both material and light in the program cpp file, I paste all the code now, i think nothing was lost, but there was still no color show up.

Comment: But your material has no data. I'm not sure, but that probably means black for all colors. Try to set at least the diffuse color to white.

Comment: Thank you Nico, I update the code and set a red color for my material, but there is still no color.

Comment: Can you clear the backbuffer to a non-black color? Red is probably not the best option either, because you expect your object to be red. This will give you information on whether the mesh is actually drawn. Furthermore, take a look at PIX, if there are transformation or backface culling problems (it will render wireframe for draw calls).

Comment: that's not the case, i found the root cause: if you disable the pixel shader in effect file, you should also disable the vertex shader, so set both of them to null, it works! thank you Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure it out myself, the vertex shader and pixel shader cannot omitted, If you don't want to use shader to compute light, you can specify them as null

```
pixelShader = null;
pixelShader = null;
```